The black out bug in Lenovo Tab M10 HD Gen 2
I was using my Lenovo Tab M10 HD and the screen just went black. But I still can use the screen.
Can anyone help how to make the screen light up?

Dunno if it's the same cause, but with my Nexus 5, I got the screen turned back on by sliding the brightness bar blindly.

Does the tablet behaves like it is still running and just the display is off (notification sound, vibrate, ..)?  What happens if you press and hold the power button for 10 seconds? Most devices do in such a case perform a hard reset and start booting do you see, hear or feel anything from the tablet?

ok how to fix it
